# How to perform an index request with the Python ElasticSearch library with a different content type

Tags: python, elasticsearch

Is it possible to send data with a different content type using the `index` method from the Python `elasticsearch` library? [The documentation for the `ingest-attachment` plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/7.12/ingest-attachment-cbor.html) mentions that you can use the CBOR encoding to avoid encoding and decoding the attached files to and from BASE64. However, as of writing this question, even their usage example performs the request with the `requests` library rather than the ElasticSearch client:

```py
import cbor2
import requests

file = 'my-file'
headers = {'content-type': 'application/cbor'}

with open(file, 'rb') as f:
  doc = {
    'data': f.read()
  }
  requests.put(
    'http://localhost:9200/my-index-000001/_doc/my_id?pipeline=cbor-attachment',
    data=cbor2.dumps(doc),
    headers=headers
  )
```

Is it possible to do this using the `elasticsearch` library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest version of the client allows to pass custom HTTP headers and accepts binary bodies. It's possible to send different data formats using custom `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers:

```py
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

def index_file(
    client: Elasticsearch,
    index: str,
    body: bytes,
    content_type: str,
    **kwargs: dict,
) -> dict:
    return client.index(
        index,
        body,
        headers={
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": content_type,
        },
        **kwargs,
    )
```

It's necessary to also set the `Accept` header, otherwise the client might throw an exception when trying to decode the response.

This is how you can use this function to index a file using the `ingest-attachment` plugin:

```py
index_file(
    client,
    index="your_index",
    body=cbor2.dumps({"data": binary_file_content}),
    content_type="application/cbor",
    pipeline="attachment",  # For the ingest-attachment plugin.
)
```